# Unable to keep remote job running on OS X

Tags: macos, ssh

I just got a MacPro and am trying to work remotely on it. But when I ssh into it and
start a job, put it in the background, and log out, the job apparently goes to sleep. 
So when I log back in and check how long it has been running, it appears to have simply 
gone to sleep for the period I'm logged out, and then restarts when I log back in. 
Tried nohup/disown and a bunch of other fixes proposed for related situations, but these 
do not seem to work. I also tried "| at" to see if I could start the job at a fixed time, 
but when I logout and come back later, I find this is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use OSX, but I do use Linux, and I believe the same command is available to you.  Try running "screen", which will allow you to attach and detach from a virtual console which will continue to run.